# Setting application-specific keyboard shortcuts in Gnome 3.16

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, nautilus

I would like to associate a specific action in Nautilus (namely 'Open in Terminal') with a keyboard shortcut so that I don't have to use the mouse to open the current working directory in a new terminal.

[The official documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) (see section *Change keyboard shortcuts*) states that this is possible and gives instructions on how to achieve it, but I can't get it to work. Please see the following image to better understand what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut to the last item in the context menu, but the method described in the official documentation doesn't seem to work for me. Is there a secret to making it work?

Comment: Unfortunately _gtk accels_ is completely broken in `gnome 3.16` (I mean for all apps: `gedit`, `nautilus` etc...). In theory, you should be able to customize the shortcuts via `~/.config/nautilus/accels` e.g. to assign Alt+F5 to open-terminal you should have a line like: `(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal" "<Alt>F5")` (note there's no leading `;`). Alas, it no longer works...

Comment: What a pity! Yes, I already encountered the configuration file you mentioned, but changing it didn't have any effect on the accelerators. Hopefully the next Gnome will fix this quite annoying issue.

Answer (score 0):

[As pointed out by don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204627/setting-application-specific-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-3-16#comment344918_204627), keyboard accelerators at present are defective in Gnome Shell. I will file a bug in Gnome's Bugzilla in the unlikely case that nobody has done so yet.

Comment: Well, if you haven't already filed a bug report... it's not a bug. See [this commit](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-December/msg01370.html).