# Syntax of GTK applications' configuration files in ~/.config

Tags: configuration, nautilus

I often find myself in trouble when I try to edit configuration files from the `~/.config/` folder. I expect any change I make to them to be effective, at least after restarting the application or having logged out/inagain.

But they sometimes don't. Here for example, I try to edit `~/.config/nautilus/accels`, changing the line:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "<Primary>Delete")
```

by:

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "Delete")
```

After I close Nautilus, then restart it, or log out-then-in, the "Delete" key stil doesn't do anything. More disturbing, the output of `head ~/.config/nautilus/accels` is:

```
; nautilus GtkAccelMap rc-file         -*- scheme -*-
; this file is an automated accelerator map dump
;
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Start Volume" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Trash" "<Primary>Delete")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Save Search" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Location Poll" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/Set As Wallpaper" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Folder with Selection" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Tab9" "<Alt>
```

just like I hadn't done anything! This means to me that some information is stored elsewhere in some way. What should I do, after having edited a file in `~/.config/`, to make the changes effective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` starts a comment. So a line starting with `;` is ignored.

And probably nautilus overwrites the config file at close. So you should stop nautilus, delete the `;` and start nautilus again.

Comment: Correct but note that `gtk_accels` is currently [broken](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204627) (3.16) so YMMV.

Comment: Okay, so this only has something to do with Nautilus then? I also have the same problem with `sed "s/cursor_shape = 0/cursor_shape = 1/" -i ~/.config/tilda/config_0`, which doesn't seem to change anything and is restored to initial state when I restart `tilda`. Is there no common behavior for all files in `~/.config`?

Comment: @don_crissti Well, I guess I've been mistaking then. I thought there was something the user should do after having edited config files to make them effective, something that would mean `apps read config files now`. But there is not. Let's investigate independently about the `tilda` problem then. Should I delete this post?

Comment: At least for user scripts for Nautilus 3.16 and later, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/